# exclude directory structure in output with grunt-concat-json

Tags: json, gruntjs, concatenation

my JSON files are located at the following path, I want to combine them to a single JSON with key equal to the name of the file.

```
src/
  john/
    doe/
       one.json
       two.json
       three.json
```

And if my grunt-concat-json is structured this way:

```
   "concat-json": {
        "en": {
            src: "src/john/doe/*.json",
            dest: "output.json"
        }
    }
```

output.json:

```
{
 "src": {
    "john": {
      "doe": {
         one: {...},
         two: {...}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want my output.json to be

```
{
  one: {...},
  two: {...}
}
```

How do I achieve this?.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

Change the concat-json in grunt as follows:

```
"concat-json": {
        "en": {
            src: "**/*.json",
            cwd: "src/john/doe",
            dest: "output.json"
        }
    }
```

Here the output.json will be:

```
{
  one: {...},
  two: {...}
}
```